Retrieve LwM2M path via Rule Chain
Description
I am working with the LwM2M implementation of ThingsBoard. In our organisation, we use another platform called Tartabit as an LwM2M server, but we want to switch.
In Tartabit we use the LwM2M path structure to send information about the devices to our own API.
When a resource is observed in TB, the notify data you get from the device is shown by the attribute key in the following format:
For example, the device object 3 (LwM2M OMA standard) will provide the time every 5 seconds in resource 13.
{
    "currentTime": "Oct 16, 2024 13:36 PM",
    "modelNumber": "Model 500"
}

Is it possible to get the path info via the Rule Chain?
So I can see this message comes from "/3/0/13" so I can forward it to our API?
We use the path structure in our API, so if it is not possible ThingsBoard might not be the right solution for us.
Environment

OS: Windows 10 version 10.0.19045 Build 19045
ThingsBoard: 3.8.1 via Docker compose
Browser: Firefox 131.0.3

I tried various custom nodes from the Rule Chain section, but I can not find a way to find out from what path the message from the device came from.
I can only view the attribute key, but I want the path.
